# az.archive.ubuntu.com is down. How can I get the updates?

Tags: apt, updates, archive

When I run "sudo apt-get update" the request gets timed out, because az.archive.ubuntu.com is down. I checked whether it was just me, but it says that it is actually down. Should I just wait for for it to get fixed? Or how should I get the latest updates?

Comment: You could try a different mirror https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comment, I tried a different mirror, which solved the problem.